# Crash App android Studio

Tags: java, android

При попытке запуска приложения на смартфоне оно тут же падает:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOne,btnTwo,btnThree,btnFour,btnFive,btnSix,btnSeven,btnEight,btnNine,btnZero;

    TextView tvProcessor, tvResult;

    String processor;
    Button btnClear,btnEqual;

    Button btnPlus,btnMinus,btnMul,btnDivide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        tvProcessor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvProcessor);
        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);


        btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
        btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThree);
        btnFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFour);
        btnFive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
        btnSix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSix);
        btnSeven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSeven);
        btnEight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEight);
        btnNine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNine);
        btnZero = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnZero);


        btnPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnEqual = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);




        /**************************************************
         * Button Clear OnClickListener
         **************************************************/

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                tvProcessor.setText("");
                tvResult.setText("");
            }

            });

        /**************************************************
         * Button Numbers OnClickListener
         **************************************************/
        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "1");
            }
        });
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "2");
            }
        });
        btnThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "3");
            }
        });
        btnFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "4");
            }
        });
        btnFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "5");
            }
        });
        btnSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "6");
            }
        });
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "7");
            }
        });
        btnEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "9");
            }
        });
        btnZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "0");
            }
            /**************************************************
             * Button Math OnClickListener
             **************************************************/
        });
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "+");
            }
        });
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "-");
            }
        });
        btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "x");
            }
        });
        btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                tvProcessor.setText(processor + "/");
            }
        });
        /**************************************************
         * Button Equeal OnClickListener
         **************************************************/
        btnEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
                processor = processor.replaceAll("x", "*");

                org.mozilla.javascript.Context rhino = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();

                rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
                String result;

                try {
                    Scriptable scope = rhino.initSafeStandardObjects();
                    result = rhino.evaluateString(scope, processor,"JavaScript",1,null).toString();

                }catch (Exception e){

                    result = "Error";
                }
                tvResult.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> 12-19 18:27:31.717 12948-12948/com.example.azot2.mycalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.azot2.mycalculator, PID: 12948
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.azot2.mycalculator/com.example.azot2.mycalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at com.example.azot2.mycalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Comment: Логи в студию, а то этот чертов штатный экстрасенс опять убыл на каникулы :)

Comment: Добавил логи снизу

Comment: Три раза ` btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);` это по плану?

Comment: Блин вот этого я не заметил :D исправил и заработало